# JPlayer - send a string value back to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jplayer

I need help to modify this script. This JPlayer script gets its URL data from a **getsong.php** file which it works fine, but I need send a string value back to the getsong.php file, like example:

**getsong.php?rock**

or

**getsong.php?pop**

I need to send this string value "**?**" using these "**OnClick**" links:

```
<a href="#" onclick="new_string('code=rock')">Rock</a>
<a href="#" onclick="new_string('code=pop')">Pop</a>
```

This is the current jplayer script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var dataString_code

$(function() {
$(".new_string").click(function() {
var code = $("#code").val();
dataString_code = 'code='+ code;

return true;
});
});


$(document).ready(function(){
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
    ready: function () {
        var data = $.ajax({
          url: "getsong.php?"+ dataString_code,
          async: false
         }).responseText;

        string = data.split('|');
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            mp3: string[0]
        }).jPlayer("play");

        $('ol#artist').html(string[1]);
        $('ol#songname').html(string[2]);

    },
    ended: function (event) {  
        var data = $.ajax({
          url: "getsong.php?"+ dataString_code,
          async: false
         }).responseText;

        string = data.split('|');
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            mp3: string[0]
        }).jPlayer("play");


        $('ol#artist').html(string[1]);
        $('ol#songname').html(string[2]);

    },
    swfPath: "js",
    supplied: "mp3"

});
});

</script>
```

PLEASE HELP

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haha, okay: You are calling your function onclick="new_string('code=rock')" which triggers the execution of a function. Perfect.
But this function is not defined, e.g.

```
var new_string = function(ev) {

}
```

instead you are using:
$(".new_string").click(function() {
which would attach a new onClickHandler to an non - existing element (you are using the class - selektor of jQuery ".classname" and as far as I can see it, there is no element having the class "new_string".
So you can either:

```
<a href="#" class="new_string">Rock</a>

 $(".new_string").click(function() {
    var oThis = $(this); // this points to the "a" - DOM - element
    var code = oThis.html();
    dataString_extra = 'code='+ code;

    return true;
  });
```

or

```
<a href="#" onclick="new_string('code=rock')">Rock</a>

var new_string = function(code) {
     dataString_extra = code;

    return true;
}
```